# Match abbreviations which aren't within words with a PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm using preg_replace to provide a glossary feature on my site which shows the full unabbreviated form of an abbreviation in a tooltip when a user hovers over a matching abbreviation. The function will run over user comments to find matching abbreviations and insert the needed html etc. But I'm struggling to create a regex which will exclude abbreviations found within words. So for example

```
~rtw~i
```

Will find RTW and rtw as desired but it will also find a match within artwork.

I get I will need to find matches which don't have letters either side but how do I do that while also allowing for abbreviations at the start or end of a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use word boundaries: `\b`

Example: `~\brtw\b~i`

These will match at the beginning and end of lines too.